Error in initialize(...) :variable names are limited to 10000 bytes
I have a spreadsheet in excel where the 4th column contains messages. I need to assign each message one of three tokens “X”, “Y”, “X/Y” depending on whether only “X” or only “Y” or both occur in that message.  Next is the code.  When running, an error appears "Error in initialize(...) :variable names are limited to 10000 bytes". I don't understand what should be changed.
file_path <- "...xlsx"
data <- read_excel(file_path)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(marker = case_when(
    grepl("X", .[[4]], ignore.case = TRUE) & grepl("Y", .[[4]], ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "X/Y",
    grepl("X", .[[4]], ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "X",
    grepl("Y", .[[4]], ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "Y",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_   #
  ))


I don't know what to do

partially Answered in staging ground https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79005199

In case the link disappears: @moodymudskipper (make it an answer if you like) answered in staging ground (which should be used for structural question enhancements): try to set colnames = FALSE ? it might be that you have long text in the first row.

The thing to learn here is how initalize (and other funcs which read Excel files generate column/row names or variable names.     Tho' I have to say that whoever thought putting gigantic prose missives into a spreadsheet's cells needs some serious re-education.
